# How to correctly define a function?

Tags: python, function, definition

In python I'm trying to do the following to define a function:

```
count_letters(word) = count_vowels(word) + count_consonants(word)
```

But for some reason, it is wrong. I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: example ? expected/actual output?

Comment: You  can not set the result (`count_vowels(word) + count_consonants(word`) to a function call (`count_letters(word)`)

Comment: your functions are variables are not defined.

Comment: here's a good start: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how you declare a function in python. What you want to write is:

```
def count_letters(word):
    return count_vowels(word) + count_consonants(word)
```

That is if you already have a `count_vowels` and a `count_consonants` function.

Answer (score 4):

The result of function call `count_letters(word)` is not assignable. That's as easy as that.

I don't believe it can work in python though, you should have an error like that:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace it with a proper function definition:

```
def count_letters(word):
    return count_vowels(word) + count_consonants(word)
```

The syntax you're trying to use is not valid Python.

Comment: even if admittedly that wouldn't be an ugly syntax... `square(x) = x*x` :-)

Comment: @6502 You should look at Haskell - the definition of the `square` function is `square x = x * x`

Answer (score 2):

May be what you want to do is something like

```
def count_letters(word):
    return count_vowels(word) + count_consonants(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I gather correctly, you're trying to create a function.  However, what you have right now is not valid syntax--to Python, it looks like you're trying to assign a value to a function call (`count_letters(word)`), which is not permissible in Python. `count_letters = count_vowels(word) + count_consonants(word)` would work, but is not what you want.

What you should do in order to declare the function is the following:

```
def count_letters(word):
    return count_vowels(word) + count_consonants(word)
```

Answer (score -2):

having defined function: count_vowels(word) and count_consonants(word)

then you can do this:
count_letters = count_vowels(word) +count_consonants(word)

hope it help! thanks